# Django translation: translating URLs

Tags: django, translation, django-i18n

I'm using Django 1.11 with translations enabled. My URLs start with language code, e.g. "/en/tickets/" or "/cs/tickets/". I need to solve the following problem: I have a URL in some language (could be any of the ones I'm using - the ones in `settings.LANGUAGES`) and I need to convert it into one particular language.

Now Django offers `django.urls.translate_url()` which should be doing exactly what I want, however it seems that it works only when the original URL is in the current language.

Example (Django shell):

```
>>> from django.urls import translate_url
>>> from django.utils.translation import activate
>>> activate('en')
>>> translate_url('/en/tickets/', 'cs')
'/cs/tickets/'
>>> translate_url('/de/tickets/', 'cs')
'/de/tickets/'
>>> activate('de')
>>> translate_url('/en/tickets/', 'cs')
'/en/tickets/'
>>> translate_url('/de/tickets/', 'cs')
'/cs/tickets/'
```

I need it to be working for all the languages. How do I do that? Thank you.

**Update**
Here are my `urlpatterns`:

Project-wide:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^tickets/', include('tickets.urls')),
    # all the other apps, similar to the row above
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Application (sample):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.overview, name='tickets-overview'),
    url(r'^archive/$', views.archive, name='tickets-archive'),
    # all the other views, similar to the row above
]
```

Comment: Did you take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns?

Comment: @jgadelange Yes, I'm using that. It wouldn't work at all if I wasn't.

Comment: It's strange, but the same problem still happens four and a half years later, on Python 3.9.7 and Django 3.2.8.